# Exception is thrown when text box is blank

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two text boxes that require a numeric value to be sent to a SQL table. Text values work without an issue when sending to the SQL Table. Validation work's if the is a numeric value in the box, but when the box is blank it throws the exception

```
            private void AddPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MedToxDatabaseEntities1 db = new MedToxDatabaseEntities1())
        {
            MedToxDatabaseSP.Patient patient = new Patient();

       // **** Patient Section of the main dashboard *****

            patient.EncounterDate = DateConsult.Value;
            patient.FirstName = TxbFirstName.Text;
            patient.LastName = TxbLastName.Text;
            patient.DOB = DOB.Value;
            string MRN = TxbMRN.Text;
            patient.PatientMedicalRecordNumber = decimal.Parse(MRN);
            patient.ExposureName = CboExposure.Text;
            patient.InstitutionName = CboHospital.Text;
            patient.LocationName = CboHospitalLocation.Text;
            string Redcap = TxbRedCapNumber.Text;
            patient.RedcapNumber = decimal.Parse(Redcap);
```

Comment: Because empty string is not numerical value,

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing user-generated data into a decimal type under the assumption that it is always correct. That is never a good idea.

```
patient.RedcapNumber = decimal.Parse(Redcap);
```

should be

```
if (decimal.TryParse(Redcap, patient.RedcapNumber) == false) {
  throw new Exception("Invalid decimal number entered");
}
```

Comment: Using `TryParse` then throwing an exception defeats the purpose of using `TryParse` in the first place.

Comment: Not really because you can write an exception class specific to this case and catch it specifically in order to produce the outcome you want.

Answer (score 0):

you any use one of these

```
decimal PatientMedicalRecordNumber = decimal.Parse("0" + MRN);
```

or

```
decimal PatientMedicalRecordNumber = decimal.Parse((MRN=="")?"0":MRN);
```

or

```
decimal PatientMedicalRecordNumber=0;
decimal.TryParse(MRN, out PatientMedicalRecordNumber);
```